# Lightbox using InterImage Link with response

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, lightbox

I have a response in which I am storing both the thumbnail and the Original Images as shown below.

```
context.Response.Write("<a href='" + (tempPath & "/") + filename + "'><img src='" + (tempPath & "/thumbs/") + "t_" + filename + "'/></a>")
```

So Now how do I give the Lightbox effect

Here is my Uploadify OnComplete event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(
    function () {
        $("#Inputfile").fileUpload({
            'uploader': 'scripts/uploader.swf',
            'cancelImg': 'images/cancel.png',
            'buttonText': 'Browse Files',
            'script': 'UploadVB.ashx',
            'folder': 'uploads',
            'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
            'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
            'queueSizeLimit': 9999,
            'simUploadLimit': 2,
            'sizeLimit': 4000000,
            'multi': true,
            'auto': true,
 'onComplete': function (event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
            var paths = response.split(";");

            $("#thumbnail").append(response)
              },

    });
}
);
```

And here is my DIV element:

```
<div id="thumbnail">
Here I am able to display the thumbnail image through which I called through the response and If I click the thumbnail it's opening the Image but not with the Lightbox effect.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do after appending the response is setting up the lightbox effect.
You can also delegate the click event within #thumbnail so that for every click within thumbnail that is done on an anchor, the function will be called. you can then open the image in a lightbox.

to get you started:

```
$('#thumbnail').delegate('a', 'click', function (e) {

    // open the href inside a lightbox

    e.preventDefault(); // to prevent opening the link
});
```

Comment: Actually I am unable to give the href because both are in the response and when I split the response I get the info like this   $("#Original").append("<img src=" + paths[0] + ">")
$("#thumbnail").append("<img src=" + paths[1] + ">") and I am calling through what you said as $('#thumbnail').delegate('a', 'click', function (e) {

    ('<img src=" + paths[1] + ">')

    e.preventDefault(); // to prevent opening the link
});